# Error while installing mongo driver for PHP on amazon linux

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pecl

I tried to install the mongodb driver for PHP on Amazon Linux. 
While running `sudo pecl install mongo`, I get the error message:

```
fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/evp.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [io_stream.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

PEAR Version: 1.9.5
PHP Version: 5.3.29

I installed gcc which helped me progress further with the install till this error.

The best Guide I was able to find was here:
http://jonathanhui.com/install-mongodb-amazon-linux
PHP's guide: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: you should really use yum or apt-get(depending on your dist) to install these packages and avoid make or make install. Here are the install instructions: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`evp`  is high-level cryptographic functions.

Try to install development libraries:

Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

CentOS:
`yum install openssl-devel`

Comment: @Vor - No package libssl-dev available. at aws-ec2

Comment: libssl-dev was already installed in my case, but the answer below by @Bluex did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

The **right package** to install **is not** `libssl-dev` but

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

and now you can execute

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Don't forget to add `extension=mongodb.so` to your php.ini file.

To know which php.ini file is loaded you can create and simple php file on vps

```
<?php
   php_info()
?>
```

[Example directory php.ini in phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1rks.jpg)