# io_stream.lo Error 1 when installing php extension

Tags: php, mongodb, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to install mongo php extension on OSX 10.11 but the command:

> sudo pecl install mongo

gives the following error:

```
...
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/io_stream.c:34:
/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'openssl/evp.h' file not found
#include <openssl/evp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [io_stream.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Have you looked into installing openssl as well?

Answer (score 14):

1. `brew install openssl`
2. `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @200OK let me clarify: If you have already installed homebrew, you don't need mess up with csrutil. since it allows /usr/local to be modified. I think this is common since most of us using homebrew or macports etc. this answer is the correct one without reboot or running csrutil. (i have tested with El-capitan 10.11.2, homebrew 0.9.5 for PHP7 for mongodb driver 1.2 for PHP7 branch and of course with success)

Comment: It's possible that different version of openssl be installed on you system and hence you need to change the path on second command.

Answer (score 8):

You need to disable the Mac OSX El Capitán rootless mechanism:

1. Boot with Cmd-R
2. Open Terminal
3. Type `csrutil disable`
4. Reboot

On the Mac, You need to install Xcode, and build the symlink for the openssl comes with Xcode,
i.e.

```
cd /usr/include;
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdk/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/openssl .
```

i.e. `/usr/include/openssl` points to Xcode library.

Build your mongo php library.

Once it is done, you should have to enable the rootless security protection:

1. Boot with Cmd-R
2. Open Terminal
3. Type `csrutil enable`
4. Reboot

Comment: This definitely helped me to get the `sudo pecl install mongo` finished on latest OSX (I had rootless disabled already). +1

Answer (score 0):

> evp is high-level cryptographic functions.
>
> Try to install development libraries:
>
> Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
>
> CentOS: yum install openssl-devel

Source: [Error while installing mongo driver for PHP on amazon linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262848/error-while-installing-mongo-driver-for-php-on-amazon-linux)

Comment: Two things should be mentioned here... 1) I'm on mac not ubuntu or centos and 2) openssl is already installed and enabled...

Comment: Sounds like a very similar issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262848/error-while-installing-mongo-driver-for-php-on-amazon-linux no?

Answer (score 0):

I am using OS X and have a custom build of openssl in /usr/local/openssl

so:

```
ln -s /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution from Scott Wiersdorf seems to worked for me https://solitum.net/openssl-os-x-el-capitan-and-brew/

install opnessl through brew

```
brew install openssl
```

Link the openssl

```
$ cd /usr/local/include
$ ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl
```