# configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, configuration, autoconf

What are the commands to instal mongdb PHP extension on Ubuntu 16.04 version? I have tried pecl install but stucks with a message:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries
```

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7 please help.

I have installed libssl-dev, but that doesn't fix the problem..

```
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

Here my php version is 7 not 5.x as described in [Error while installing mongo driver for PHP on amazon linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262848/error-while-installing-mongo-driver-for-php-on-amazon-linux)

Comment: Do you have  _OpenSSL_ installed on that machine? Seems like the extension needs it. run `configure --help` in order to see if you can specify _OpenSSL_ paths or maybe to exclude it (some option that could look like: `--with-openssl=no`).

Comment: No I haven't installed, I need help on that

Comment: The post marked as a duplicate of this issue is not a duplicate. It answers a different bug. As the OP states, he has already installed libssl-dev - the solution posed by the other post. The correct answer to this question is to run `sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev openssl`

Comment: @jww it's not a duplicate of '<evp.h> not found' it's another issue and  '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' helps me

Comment: *sudo apt-get install  pkg-config* should do it for you